# Jquery setTimeout Isn't Working (Image Slideshow)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a quick slideshow for a website. I'm still working on my Javascript/jQuery, so I could probably simplify my code in the future. Regardless, I'm using the setTimeout function to increase the currentImage variable. However, it doesn't appear to be working properly, as the images do not change as time passes. The back and next buttons still work, but it seems like it's skipping one of the images.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var topofDiv = $("header").offset().top;
    var height = $("header").outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function(){    
        if($(window).scrollTop() > (topofDiv + height))
        {
            $("#nav").css("position","fixed");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#nav").css("position","static");
        }
    });
    var currentImage = 0;
    function autoPlay()
    {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            currentImage++;
        }, 1000);
    };
    function slideImage()
    {
        if(currentImage == 0)
        {
            $(".img1").fadeIn(1000).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img1").fadeOut(1000).hide();
        }
        if(currentImage == 1)
        {
            $(".img2").fadeIn(1000).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img2").fadeOut(1000).hide();
        }
        if(currentImage == 2)
        {
            $(".img3").fadeIn(1000).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img3").fadeOut(1000).hide();
        }
    };
    slideImage();
    autoPlay();
    $("#next").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("color","black");
    });
    $("#next").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("color","white");
    });
    $("#back").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("color","black");
    });
    $("#back").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("color","white");
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
        clearTimeout(autoPlay);
        currentImage++;
        if(currentImage >= 3)
        {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
        slideImage();
    });
    $("#back").click(function(){
        clearTimeout(autoPlay);
        currentImage--;
        if(currentImage < 0)
        {
            currentImage = 2;
        }
        slideImage();
    });
});
```

Comment: call `slideImage` withing the `setInteval` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.You need to call `slideimage function` inside the `setInteval` and you should use `setInterval` not `setTimeout`.So In each 1 sec currentImage value will increase by 1 and show appropriate image.When currentImage  value is greater than 3,then reset the value to zero and show the first image by calling `slideimage dunction`

```
 var interval ="";
 interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        currentImage++;
        slideImage();
        if(currentImage > 3)
        {
          currentImage = 0;
          slideImage();
        }

    }, 1000);

    function RemoveInterval() {
       clearInterval(interval );
    }
```

Call the `RemoveInterval` in the `next and back button click`

Comment: This worked, but now I'm having different issues. The back and next buttons no longer work, and there is a 1 second delay between cycling from the last to first image.

Comment: @JordanU. that's the default behaviour in the slide show.Sholuld be gap between displaying images

Comment: Is there a way to fix that? I would like it to go straight from image to image.

Comment: @JordanU. from last image first image ?

Comment: Yeah, currently it shows a blank space when moving from image 3 to image 1.

Comment: @JordanU.instead of `currentImage > 3` try `currentImage == 3`